# datatype mismatch SQLite: Android

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

It is giving me this error when I am adding JAVA string data to the TEXT data type is SQLite how to solve it?

```
public boolean addRow(Registration details) {
    String userName = details.getName();
    String userPassword = details.getPassword();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_ID, userName);
    values.put(KEY_PASS, userPassword);

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    long insert = db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    return insert != -1;
}
```

E/SQLiteLog: (20) statement aborts at 5: [INSERT INTO UserDetails(id,password) VALUES (?,?)] datatype mismatch

Comment: Is the column KEY_ID defined as TEXT?

Answer (score 0):

**In short you are probably trying to insert the *`userName`* into the wrong column.** The **id** column is likely limited to integer values *(long, int, short etc)*.

The only situations where you will get a [datatype mismatch](https://sqlite.org/rescode.html#mismatch) is if you are trying to insert a non integer value into the rowid column or an alias of the rowid column or if the column type is BOOLEAN and you try to insert a large BLOB. As you are not inserting a BLOB, then the former is the cause.

> (20) SQLITE_MISMATCH
> The SQLITE_MISMATCH error code indicates a datatype mismatch.
>
> SQLite is normally very forgiving about mismatches between the type of a value and the declared type of the container in which that value is to be stored.
>
> For example, SQLite allows the application to store a large BLOB in a column with a declared type of BOOLEAN. But in a few cases, SQLite is strict about types. The SQLITE_MISMATCH error is returned in those few cases when the types do not match.
>
> **The rowid of a table must be an integer. Attempt to set the rowid to anything other than an integer *(or a NULL which will be automatically converted into the next available integer rowid)* results in an SQLITE_MISMATCH error**.

As such either the **id** (probably) or the **password** column is defined using `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` (with or without AUTOINCRMENT or implied if the *PRIMARY KEY clause* is at the table level (after all the column definitions)).

At a guess, it may be that you have another column for the **userName**, if so then you may need to use `values.put(????, userName);` where ???? is the column into which the **userName** should be stored. This probably instead of `values.put(KEY_ID, userName);`

- Not specifying a ContentValue for the **id** column will result in a unique number being generated and will be the value returned by the insertorThrow method.

  - Note that with `insertOrThrow` method you would never get -1 returned as an exception would be thrown. You perhaps want to just use the insert method, then -1 would be returned if the row could not be inserted.

    - when you use the `insert` method the underlying generated SQL is `INSERT OR IGNORE ....` which ignores the typical conflicts.
    - when you use the `insertOrThrow` method the underlying generated SQL is  `INSERT ....` and  results in an exception if a conflict occurs.
  - If you do want to provide the **id**, rather than have it generated, then you could also have `values.put(KEY_ID, a_long_value);` (where a_long_value is that (it could be int)), you would likely then change the signature of the method to enable the value to be passed.

Alternately, you may need to change the offending the column (probably the **id** column ) to be `TEXT PRIMARY KEY` instead of `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`.

If you edit your question to show the SQL used to create the table a more specific answer can be provided.